# Как установить приложение из raw, Android

Tags: android, resources

Имеется приложение в ресурсах, в папке `raw` с названием `bochs.apk` и его нужно установить из приложения.

---

Никак не выходит установить (перепробовал уйму вариантов со `enSO` и т.д.), последний вариант установки:

```
mContext.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK).setDataAndType(
            Uri.parse("android.resource://" + mContext.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.bochs),
            "application/vnd.android.package-archive"));
```

На что получаю ошибку:

```
01-26 20:25:30.975 4584-4584/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.rostislav.dugin.osloader, PID: 4584
                                                 android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=android.resource://com.rostislav.dugin.osloader/2131165184 typ=application/vnd.android.package-archive flg=0x10000000 }
                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1792)
                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1512)
                                                     at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1364)
                                                     at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:1338)
                                                     at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:323)
                                                     at com.rostislav.dugin.osloader.ui.presenter.SettingsPresenter.onInstallBochsClick(SettingsPresenter.java:94)
                                                     at com.rostislav.dugin.osloader.ui.view.fragments.SettingsFragment.lambda$setUpViews$3(SettingsFragment.java:117)
                                                     at com.rostislav.dugin.osloader.ui.view.fragments.SettingsFragment$$Lambda$3.onClick(Unknown Source)
                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4848)
                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20260)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5624)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

---

Что я делаю не так и как это исправить?

Comment: Беглое гугленье говорит что так не получится и надо сначала записать файл куда-нить из ресурсов и только потом устанавливать

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, хм...Распаковать по пути `Android/data/мой_пакет/temp` и потом установить?

Comment: не уверен, что именно по такому пути, но, да, в любой доступный приложению каталог.